# regex: get list of the locations of captured groups, not matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Example string: `#ABC ABC@ #ABC@ ABC`

Example regex: `/(?:[^#])(ABC)(?!@)/g` (only matches `ABC` in the example)

I need to get a list of matches [[start,end],...] but not include the first group, which is only there because JS regex doesn't support lookbehind.

(Note: assume that the captured and uncaptured parts can be of any length, not just 1 or 3 characters like in the example)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get the indices where the groups matched inside the string.

As a workaround, make sure you capture the whole part of the pattern before the necessary capturing group/pattern part. Then, manipulate the match index and group legnth values as shown below:

```js
var re = /([^#]|^)ABC(?!@)/g; 
var str = 'ABC #ABC ABC@ #ABC@ ABC';
var pos = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  pos.push([m.index+m[1].length, m.index+m[0].length]);
}
console.log(pos);
```